# Can't get the telerik radgridview to highlight the SelectedItem when binding to viewmodel with a selecteditem already set

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik

I have a screen on which I have a telerik RadGridView as the parent/master control. Then I have a child usercontrol showing the details for the selected item.

My grid is set up thus:

```
<telerik:RadGridView  
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
 CanUserFreezeColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
 RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding LinkedCases}" 
 SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single"
 IsBusy="{Binding LinkedCasesLoading}" 
 ShowColumnFooters="True" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

CurrentlySelectedItem is a property on the viewmodel.
It is working correctly and populating the details control correctly.

My problem comes when I navigate away and then back to this screen.

The screen is recreated from scratch, but my viewmodel is retrieved from the viewmodel locator (using MVVM Light and SimpleIOC).
The Viewmodel is in exactly the condition I require it to be. The Parent grid populates correctly, the child details populate correctly. CurrentlySelectedItem on the ViewModel is populated, but the grid doesn't highlight the selected row.

I've tried with and without Updatesourcetrigger and IsSynchronisedWithCurrentItem but these cause it to select the first row in the grid and highlight that - and thus overwrite my previous value in CurrentlySelectedItem, which isn't what I'm after.

Anyone got any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: have you verified the SelectedItem binding working or not when you navigate back to your screen again, just put a DebugConverter in binding and check if it is called, I am asking so because I have faced relatively similar problem with `RadListBox` where `SelectedItem ` binding stops working when you click on the RadListBox Item.

Comment: yes - everything seems to be working fine - except it's not highlighting when initially populated. Once I click on a row it then highlights it and populates the details control. The problem with it is that because selected item is set, the details are populated - but it's not clear what row in the parent grid they belong too.

Comment: Try calling UpdateLayout() on the Telerik gridview when the page is loaded (or you navigate to the page). I would guess that your Telerik grid is correctly bound to the selected item but it just needs to update its layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't get a reference to the Grid on the page loaded or navigate to - I'd named it CaseGridView and although it recognised it was a RadGridView, it returned null. I just assumed it hadn't created the control at this point so because I'd named the control, and tried using that to reference the control in the controls events, which was also failing.

Found that it worked on DataLoaded event if I used sender:

```
 private void CaseGridView_DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as RadGridView;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            grid.SelectedItem = vm.CurrentlySelectedItem;
            if (grid.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also added the scrollIntoView part so that it would ensure it was visible on the screen.

Comment: I had this issue and had a sneaking suspicion the event in my page was "too soon" as well. I would set the SelectedItem to a valid object but when I checked it on the next line of code in the debugger the SelectedItem was still null. I refactored my code to the dataloaded event and problem solved. Thanks!!!